# Can I define implementation of methods on Rhino Mocked objects?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, rhino-mocks

With Rhino.Mocks, once I Mock an Interface I can:

- Set up "return" values for non void methods on the mocked object
- Inspect how and with what values certain methods were called with

However, is it possible to selectively define an Implementation for methods on mocked objects?

Ideally I'd like to do this (RhinoImplement is the Rhino extension I'm hoping exists!):

```
var messages = new List<IMessage>();

IBus bus = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IBus>();

bus.RhinoImplement(b => b.Send(Arg<IMessage>.Is.Anything), imess => messages.Add(imess));

//now run your test on the Class that uses IBus

//now, I can inspect my local (List<IMessage>)messages collection
```

### Update with Answer

Thanks to Patrick's answer below, the correct code to achieve the above is:

```
var messages = new List<IMessage>();

IBus bus = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IBus>();

bus
    .Expect(b => b.Send(Arg<IMessage>.Is.Anything))
    .WhenCalled(invocation => messages.Add((IMessage)invocation.Arguments[0]))
    .Repeat.Any() //the repeat part is because that method might be called multiple times

//now run your test on the Class that uses IBus

//now, I can inspect my local (List<IMessage>)messages collection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the "WhenCalled" method:

[Rhino Mocks - Set a property if a method is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349364/rhino-mocks-set-a-property-if-a-method-is-called)

Comment: thanks patrick, that worked, but only when Send was called for the first time. Any idea why? does the expectation or WhenCalled only work on the first call? thanks again

Comment: don't worry, fixed it. just had to put a .Repeat.Any(). cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The following code works using a Rhino stub instead of a Mock. To  stub out a method with side-effects.

```
    private IGuy DefaultDood()
    {
        var guyStub = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IGuy>();

        guyStub.Expect(u => u.DrinkHouseholdProducts(Arg<string>.Is.Anything)).WhenCalled(invocation =>
            {
                guyStub.JustDrank = ((string)invocation.Arguments.First());
                guyStub.FeelingWell = false;
            }
        );

        return guyStub;
    }
```